# WebDAV server using IIS: HTTP error 412

Tags: iis, webdav

I'm setting up a WebDAV server in my Windows 7 desktop, using IIS 7.5. The aim is for a WebDAV client app in my Iphone to be able to access and sync a series of files in a given folder in the PC. It's all in my own home network, and I'll be the only one syncing files.

Anyway, I've set everything up, but here is something really odd:

- If I create a file in my Iphone, and then sync it to the Windows desktop, and then delete it in my Iphone... it deletes the file in the Windows desktop the next time I sync, as it should.
- But if I create a file in my PC, sync it to my Iphone, and then delete it in my Iphone, the next time I sync it won't delete the file in the PC. It will return the **HTTP error code 412** (**Precondition failed**).

I have enabled tracing in IIS, and looking at the request headers, I don't see the WebDAV client sending any precondition. Here is what it says:

Data about the HTTP request:

```
SiteId 1 
AppPoolId DefaultAppPool 
ConnId 1610612964 
RawConnId 0 
RequestURL http://192.168.1.111:80/Notebooks/filename.txt 
RequestVerb DELETE
```

Request headers:

```
Headers Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: es-es
Host: 192.168.1.111
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 19:37:37 GMT
If-None-Match: "1ab8c9f371d11:0"
User-Agent: Notebooks 8.1.2 ( iPhone; iOS 8.4.1; es_ES)
```

And here is the only thing that the module says in its warning message:

```
ModuleName WebDAVModule 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 412 
HttpReason Precondition Failed 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation was correctly completed. (0x0)
```

The above were the errors shown in IIS tracing. As for the regular Web server log:

```
192.168.1.230 - (my PC name) [07/Oct/2015:23:13:59 +0200] "PROPFIND /Notebooks/filename.txt HTTP/1.1" 207 509
192.168.1.230 - (my PC name) [07/Oct/2015:23:13:59 +0200] "DELETE /Notebooks/filename.txt HTTP/1.1" 412 1738
```

I have been in touch with the developer of the Iphone WebDAV client, and he says that, in his experience, this tends to suggests permission problems, but I have checked the permissions of the files in Windows, and they are fine. By this I mean that I check the files that I can delete from WebDAV, and then the ones that give me the 412 error... and both have identical permissions.

What else could it be?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I thought so at first, but there are plenty of questions with similar subjects to mine in the tags "iis" and "webdav". Anyway, how do I move a question, other than reposting it completely by hand? I don't see any links to do so.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the SO is flooded by off-topic questions. You have to re-post there and delete here. There's no "automatic move".